# Activity Multibinding dagger 2 in Android Library

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, android-library, dagger-2

I am following this link http://frogermcs.github.io/activities-multibinding-in-dagger-2/ for implementing below scenario using dagger 2

Consider a scenario where in the MainActivity resides in Android library and has an injection for a interface X. The implementation class of interface X resides in main app. Then how will this multibinding structure will have to restructured for this scenario ?

Andorid library

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Inject
X object;

}
```

Main App

```
class Ximpl implements X {
@Inject
x(){}

}
```